# Best Way to Index All JSONB Fields With Boolean Values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am creating a table that has a `features` jsonb column. There will be a dynamic set of features (each row can have an unknown set of features). Each feature is boolean true/false values.

Example:

- Row 1: feature: { "happy": true, "tall": false, "motivated": true }
- Row 2: feature: { "happy": true, "fast": true, "strong": false }
- Row 3: feature: { "smart": true, "fast": true, "sleepy": false }

What would be the best way to index this column such that I can make queries to find all rows with featureX = true? All the examples I have looked up seem to need a field name to base the index on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an index on the complete JSON value:

```
create index on the_table using gin (features);
```

It can be used for e.g. the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from the_table
where features @> '{"happy": true}'
```

Another method would be to not store key/value pairs, but only list the features that are "true" in an array: `["happy", "motivated"]` and then use the `?` operator. This way the JSON value is a bit smaller and that might be more efficient.

```
select *
from the_table
where features ? 'happy'
```

or if you want to test for multiple features:

```
select *
from the_table
where features ?| array['happy', 'motivated']
```

That too can make use of the GIN index

Comment: It might be worth noting that a query on a boolean is very likely to be so unselective that, while the index can theoretically be used, it could be slower than just doing the table scan.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! If I am searching for multiple features (which I definitely will), is storing as an array faster to lookup? In the current schema, would it fall back to table scan if I had to do something like `where features @> '{"happy": true, "motivated": true}'` ?

Comment: `features @> '{"happy": true, "motivated": true}'` should make use of the GIN index if it makes sense. Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)