# PostgreSQL JSONB Array Row Must Exist in Passed in Array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am using a jsonb column to store features in an array (I followed @a_horse_with_no_name 's advise in [Best Way to Index All JSONB Fields With Boolean Values in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759162/best-way-to-index-all-jsonb-fields-with-boolean-values-in-postgresql/58761686#58761686)).

Example:

```
feature
------------------------------
[ "happy", "motivated" ]
[ "happy", "fast", "strong" ]
[ "smart", "fast" ]
[ "happy" ]
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE feature <@ '["happy"]';
```

should return only row 4.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE feature <@ '["happy", "motivated"]';
```

should return row 1 and row 4.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE feature <@ '["happy", "motivated", "fast", "strong", "smart"]';
```

should return all 4 rows.

I have the column GIN indexed. From what I understand `?|` would be more performant, but I need to use `<@` because the rows must exist in the array.  `?|` would only be able to find any key element from array in the rows, not the inclusion of each row in the array.

Any workarounds to use `?|` vs the `<@` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you used text[] rather than JSONB, then <@ would be indexable directly.

If you really need JSONB, then you could use ?| to get the index usage and <@ to rule out the false positives:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE feature ?| '{"happy", "motivated"}' feature <@ '["happy", "motivated"]';
```

One caveat is that the above will not return empty arrays, while just the <@ would.

Comment: If I were to use text[], what is the proper index to use? Gin index? I did an explain and i am getting a Seq Scan. `Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..13.12 rows=1 width=296)   Filter: (feature <@ '{happy,motivated}'::text[])`.

Comment: Correct.  With a tiny table, it won't use the index because reading the whole table is faster.  You either need a large table, or need to `set enable_seqscan=off`, to see the index scan.